# Cannot connect to my sql docker container anymore

Tags: java, mysql, docker, jdbc

I have a selenium framework that uses a sql docker container to get it's testdata from. I have used a base image with sql version 5.7 to build the container. The code I have written used to work, but not anymore. This is my code:

```
public class SQLconnection {

public static Connection dataBaseConnection() throws SQLException {

    System.out.println("-------- MySQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?useSSL=false","martijn","123");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }

    return connection;
}
```

}

To build the container I have used the dockerfile below:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD 123
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE Users
ENV MYSQL_USER martijn
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD 123
ADD script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
EXPOSE 3306
```

The error I am getting when executing my code is the following:

> Connection Failed! Check output console
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
>   link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

I am quite new to this so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you start your container?

For your code to work you have 2 major options:

1. Start container with `network=host` to disable additional networks created and let container join your host's network:

   ```
   docker run -d --network=host your-sql-image
   ```

   Here you don't need to expose ports.
2. Expose ports from container

   ```
   docker run -d -p 3306:3306 your-sql-image
   ```

### UPD

People are likely to be confused with `EXPOSE` command in `Dockerfile`. It **does not** actually expose anything (haha!), but is used more to notify users on the ports your container is going to expose:

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
>   more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
>   to high-order ports.

You can easily expose ports even if they are not listed in `EXPOSE` directive. By the way, when exposing ports, you are often mapping them to different ones, for example `-p 10000:3306`. And inside `Dockerfile` how do you suppose to know the future value of `host's` port to be used when exposing.

Comment: Man, I can't thank you enough!! I started my container without the -p flags, because I thought it was enough to expose port 3306 in my docker file, when I would build the image. It works now! But why do I need to specify the -p flag when I already have 3306 exposed in my dockerfile? Thanks again man!

Comment: You are welcome! Updated the post considering your new question

Comment: Thanks again, awesome!